# JAX-RS Servlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I receive below exception at Tomcat startup :

```
SEVERE: Servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in web application [/MyWebApp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does this mean that WebappClassLoaderBase cannot be found at startup?

as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html details :

> "Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
>       The forName method in class Class.
>       The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
>       The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
>       but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found."

But `WebappClassLoaderBase` is on my classpath.

Comment: Do you have Servlet.jar file in your classspath ?

Comment: _Does this mean that `WebappClassLoaderBase` cannot be found at startup?_ No, it does not. But the error message of the `ClassNotFoundException` should contain the name of the class, that has not been found - so I suspect it is empty, and the real problem is that you've misconfigured something (by not entering the class name in a place where it is expected/required).

Comment: @pcj I have servlet-api-2.5.jar on classpath, is specific version of Servlet.jar

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek as the name of the class has not been found, is this a design flaw in JAX as the name of class that is not being found should be detailed in error message. It is very difficult using the current exception to discover the missing class.

Comment: With a stacktrace not telling which class is missing, nobody can help you. What versions are you using (Tomcat, Jersey, ...), what does your web.xml servlet mapping look like?

Comment: Well it appears to happening before an Jersey classes are loaded, so the first place I would look is the Jersey config (namely the web.xml). Please show it.

Comment: You should search in your web.xml where there might be a <servlet-class></servlet-class> with so an empty name where it should be the classname to use as a servlet